# Blue card state for unemployed person

Tags: resident-permit, blue-card, freelance, unemployment-benefits

I am a **BlueCard** holder for 32 months in Germany. I lost my job in the 29th month and registered on Arbeitsagentur immediatelly. Now I want to clarify 3 cases.

1. How long can I stay in Germany maximum during unemployment status (for job search)?
2. Can I still apply for a Permanent Residence Permit after 33 months though unemployed?
3. What about if I register as a freelancer (company out of EU), can I apply for Permanent Residence Permit with freelancer status?